# Add special characters after Eval in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I add the **&** character after an eval in ASP.NET C#

I have this line

```
<asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server" CssClass="item"  ImageUrl="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" 
data-src='<%# "http://www.example.com/images/"+Eval("ThumbnailFile")+"&width=200" %>'
 AlternateText='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
```

and I get the link like this `http://www.example.com/images/thumbnail.jpg&amp;width=200`

but I need the link to be `http://www.example.com/images/thumbnail.jpg&width=200`

Comment: I tested with a HyperLink and the properties of the link show `&` although the source HTML of the page shows `&amp;`. The browser interprets it correctly, apparently. For the image, I also see `&amp;` in the HTML output but the properties of the element show `&`. Hard-coding a value with `&`, not using `Eval`, gives me the same behavior.

Comment: for me the image is not displayed if the link contains &amp; I use a javascript image gallery and it does not display the image with the &amp;

Comment: Do you get the same result if you hard-code the `data-src` attribute, without using the binding expression?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Very strange! but yes! I still get the &amp; with the hard-coded string data-src="/test.jpg&width=200" it automatically converts it to &amp; when I view it in browser

Comment: I also get that in all cases, but the browser seems to know what to do with it (in most cases at least).

Comment: I also have tried with .Replace("&amp;","&") and it still does not replace that

Comment: hmm which javascript image gallery are you using? @MarioM

Comment: @MarioM have you tried using jQuery .replace? just throwing suggestions out there

Comment: @terbubbs No, I have not tried that, how can I do that?

Comment: @terbubbs I use this gallery http://www.final-tiles-gallery.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` in your `data-src` attribute:

```
data-src='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("http://www.example.com/images/"+Eval("ThumbnailFile")+"&width=200") %>'
```